# Format a write-protected USB stick

Tags: usb-storage, format, write-protect

I need some help with formatting my USB stick. It says it's a write-protected and when I try to remove the protection using the following path:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies
```

and the value is already `0`.

What should I do? any ideas?

Comment: CMD process works for me. See this http://m.wikihow.com/Disable-Write-Protection

Comment: I tried it also and doesn't work for me.